# Symfony2 Dynamic Logout Target?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a working Symfony2 application that properly logs users in and out, and when logging out it properly redirects the user to the home page.

I'd like to keep them on their current page when the log out, only without their logged-in privileges.

My question is:

**Can I *dynamically* set the page the user is directed to when they log out?**

Comment: when logging out it properly redirects to the home page because in the logout action it set to redirect at home action. so the logging out action redirect user to the current action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed a Logout Success Handler, and this is how I implemented it:

**security.yml**:

```
logout:
    success_handler: acme.security.logout_success_handler
```

**config.yml**:

```
services:
    acme.security.logout_success_handler:
        class: Acme\DefaultBundle\Handler\LogoutSuccessHandler
```

**Symfony/src/Acme/DefaultBundle/Handler/LogoutSuccessHandler.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DefaultBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class LogoutSuccessHandler extends ContainerAware implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $target_url = $request->query->get('target_url')
                      ? $request->query->get('target_url')
                      : "/";
        return new RedirectResponse($target_url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What you need is a logout success handler.

Define the logout handler in the security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        admin_area:
            logout:
                success_handler: acme.security.logout_success_handler
```

And the handler goes like this:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class LogoutSuccessHandler extends ContainerAware implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
    {
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        // dynamic route logic

        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('dynamic_route_name'));
    }
}
```

Btw... Please remove the unwanted imports and Hope this helps! :D

Here is the services.yml

```
services:
    acme.security.logout_success_handler:
        class: Acme\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Handler\LogoutSuccessHandler
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```