# Dynamic Logout Target For Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have implemented a basic authentication system using symfony framework. It is working as expected. But I would like to have one more feature.

After `logout`, I should be redirected to previous location. I followed following question for implementing this feature.
[Symfony2 Dynamic Logout Target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461599/symfony2-dynamic-logout-target)

But it is giving me one error message.

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "dynamic_route_name" as
>   such route does not exist.

Any Idea, why this is happening?

Comment: Does your route have this `dynamic_route_name` method ?

Comment: Did you defined a controller Action who matches the route name `dynamic_route_name`?

Comment: No. I don't have any such dynamic_route. Actually I want to redirect to previous page after logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have used the following code from the example post

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('dynamic_route_name'));
```

This expects the route `dynamic_route_name` to exist, which wouldn't really take you to the previous page, but to a static route (where you can do all sorts of tricks in the controller if you want to)

Instead you can rather try the second answer and use

```
$target_url = $request->query->get('target_url')
                  ? $request->query->get('target_url')
                  : "/";
    return new RedirectResponse($target_url);
```

Where `target_url` is the route you want to redirect to (set in the template to the current route) or any other logic you can use to determine which page to go to

To redirect to current page after logout, you may set logout link as follows:

```
<a href="{{ path('logout', {'target_url': app.request.uri})  }}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to redirect to previous page after logout. So, are you saying to redirect to a static route and then add some custom logic?

Comment: Well it depends. If you are currently on E.G /some/page, when logging out do you want to return back to /some/page, or the page you were on before /some/page?

Comment: I want to return to /some/page

Comment: In that case you can use the above code, and set the target_url in the template to the current url using something like <a href="{{ path('logout', {'target_url' : app.request.uri }) }}"/>Logout</a>

Comment: is an ajax logout and a page refresh out of question ?

Comment: No it's not, you can then do the ajax logout then you don't need a custom route and controller or the logout handler